# Differentiate items from array list in recycle view adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display feed like Instagram i am using 2 layouts for that.
Using Recycle view in that adapter i check with view type for multi image or single image, for multi image i am using view pager .

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case ModelUser.VIEW_PAGER:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_multi_photo, parent, false);
                return new TextTypeViewHolder(view);
            case ModelUser.IMAGE_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_photo, parent, false);
                return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;


    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        ModelUser object = dataSet.get(listPosition);
        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.type1) {
                case ModelUser.VIEW_PAGER:

                    final SliderPagerAdapter sliderPagerAdapter = new SliderPagerAdapter((Activity) mContext, slider_image_list);
                    ((TextTypeViewHolder) holder).mvViewPager.setAdapter(sliderPagerAdapter);

                    ((TextTypeViewHolder) holder).mvViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            addBottomDots(position, ((TextTypeViewHolder) holder).ll_dots);
                            page = position;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                        }
                    });
```

On setting adapter data i am using

```
 MultiViewTypeAdapter feedMainAdapter = new MultiViewTypeAdapter(feed_list,imagelist,context);
                                        RecylerFeed.setAdapter(feedMainAdapter);
```

feed_list is for single image and imagelist is for multiimage so,my problem is in imagelist i am getting list of every images how can i differentiate those images for particular user?

Comment: add list of images for user in `ModelUser` . and pass `object.getListOfImagesForSelectedUser()` in  ViewPager Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my problem is in imagelist i am getting list of every images

Because, passing `slider_image_list` in `SliderPagerAdapter` which contains all user images.

> how can i differentiate those images for particular user?

Create new user specific image list from `slider_image_list` before passing to ViewPager:

```
case ModelUser.VIEW_PAGER:
  //Create new List of images  for current user from `slider_image_list`
   ArrayList<> currentUserImages=new ArrayList<>();
   final SliderPagerAdapter sliderPagerAdapter = 
               new SliderPagerAdapter((Activity) mContext, currentUserImages);

  ....
 break;
```

Comment: Please look into this question I tried to solve it but could not solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513672/errorunable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebugandroidtest-compileclasspath @ρяσѕρєя K

Answer (score 0):

Add RecyclereView in

```
feed_multi_photo
```

And inside `onBindViewHolder`

```
    switch (object.type1) {
                    case ModelUser.VIEW_PAGER:
   //Impement Nested RecyclerAdapter of Multiple Image using imagelist


     InnerRecyclerviewAdapter adapter=new InnerRecyclerviewAdapter(context,imagelist);
     holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```